# html+javascript: semantic-ui: how to align headers in columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

I have html like this with two columns(`ui two column middle aligned very relaxed stackable grid`):

```
Groups  | Users
groups  | users
content | content
```

`Groups` and `Users` are `ui header`. I want
align them by vertical, how can I achieve such behaviour?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui two column middle aligned very relaxed stackable grid">
  <div class="column">
<h3 class="ui header">Groups</h3>
<div class="ui relaxed divided list">
  
  <div class="item">
    <i class="large fax middle aligned icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">Group1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <i class="large fax middle aligned icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">Group2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <i class="large fax middle aligned icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">Group2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
<button class="ui button">
  Rename
</button>
<button class="ui button">
  Remove
</button>
<button class="ui button">
  Create new
</button>
  </div>
  <div class="ui vertical clearing divider"></div>
  <div class="center aligned column">
<h3 class="ui header">Users</h3>
<div class="ui relaxed divided list">
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="ui left floated compact segment">
      <div class="ui fitted checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox">
 <label></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <i class="large user middle aligned icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">User1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="ui left floated compact segment">
      <div class="ui fitted checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox">
 <label></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <i class="large user middle aligned icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">User2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="ui left floated compact segment">
      <div class="ui fitted checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox">
 <label></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <i class="large user middle aligned icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">User3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="ui left floated compact segment">
      <div class="ui fitted checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox">
 <label></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <i class="large user middle aligned icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">User4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
<button class="ui button">
  <i class="add user icon"></i>
  Add User
</button>
<button class="ui button">
  <i class="remove user icon"></i>
  Remove user
</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from my snippet, `Users` above `Groups` by vertical, how can I force them to be on the same level by vertical?

Comment: at the moment they are vertically centred, so just remove `middle` class from their container, so they will be top aligned